# Django get_absolute_url with ForeignKey parameter not working

Tags: python, django

I am using the get_absolute_url method to get the url for a dynamic query, however when the link is displayed, it only shows the first parameter and not the second in the get_absolute_url method. It only does this when I use the ForeignKey of the model as the first parameter. Below is the code.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
topic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
forum_id = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
topic_title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
topic_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
topic_user_id = models.IntegerField()
topic_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
topic_replies = models.IntegerField(default=0)
topic_is_locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
topic_is_sticky = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % _(u'self.topic_title')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    **return '/forums/%i/%i/' % (self.forum_id, self.topic_id)**
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the string returned from `topic_instance.get_absolute_url()`?

Comment: Could you show the corresponding parts of your urls.py as well? Though it would be probably better to use the permalink-decorator to reverse your urls (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.permalink)

Comment: I found the answer to my problem, but will definitely look into this as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/forums/%s/%s/' % (str(self.forum_id.pk), self.topic_id)
```

edit: [jerzyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646765/jerzyk) comment mentions these other points:

1. using @permalink with get_absolute_url and reversing the url using the view and arguments so you don't have to hardcode the urls.
2. using _id instead of .pk

   ```
   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return '/forums/%s/%s/' % (self.forum_id_id, self.topic_id)
   ```

Comment: but this is generating extra db query each time it is executed, much better ir will be: '/forums/%i/%i/' % (self.forum_id_id, self.topic_id), another story is that this is not so good approach, much better it will be to use permalink decorator http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.permalink